# Understanding how DNS queries work at a deeper level

Tags: networking, dns

It's currently 04:40 AM and I am stuck on something I simply do not understand. I am trying to look up a domain's nameservers directly by using the DNS protocol. If I send a `host -t ns google.com 1.1.1.1` and monitor it with Wireshark, I can see the full query of the DNS query. However, I cannot figure out, why some ASCII characters are used one time, but not another time. Here is an example:

```
0000   70 4d 7b 94 dd e0 00 d8 61 a9 c5 ec 08 00 45 00   pM{.....a.....E.
0010   00 38 d6 ff 00 00 80 11 9f 50 c0 a8 01 bb 01 01   .8.......P......
0020   01 01 e8 40 00 35 00 24 a0 19 9e f7 01 00 00 01   ...@.5.$........
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f   .......google.co
0040   6d 00 00 02 00 01                                 m.....
```

In this DNS query, I am looking up the nameservers for `google.com`. The actual query starts at `06 07`.

`06` in ASCII is ACK/Acknowledgment.

---

Now, if we take a look at `gmail.com` instead:

```
0000   70 4d 7b 94 dd e0 00 d8 61 a9 c5 ec 08 00 45 00   pM{.....a.....E.
0010   00 37 d7 00 00 00 80 11 9f 50 c0 a8 01 bb 01 01   .7.......P......
0020   01 01 e8 58 00 35 00 23 8f cc 6f e2 01 00 00 01   ...X.5.#..o.....
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 05 67 6d 61 69 6c 03 63 6f 6d   .......gmail.com
0040   00 00 02 00 01                                    .....
```

the query starts at `05 67` instead.

`05` is ENQ/Enquiry.

---

Why are they different? If I try to send `06` instead of `05` the DNS server gives me no response but Wireshark tells me:

> Unknown extended label

I've seen `05`, `06`, and `09` so far. `09` is my biggest "wat" of all time, because it's a HT/Horizontal Tab.

Anyone with a lot of DNS knowledge who can help me here? I'm not looking for "just use dig/nslookup/host command". I'm currently trying to research a bit on the DNS protocol, and this is a thing I do not understand.

Good read where I got a lot of help: http://dev.lab427.net/dns-query-wth-netcat.html

Comment: The own page you link to explains what the first byte is and why it changes: "Query string, null-terminated, each section starts with length number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a binary protocols like this, you can't assume each byte corresponds to the matching ASCII character.

Take a look at section 4.1.2 of the DNS RFC (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).

The domain name in a DNS request is broken up into "labels".  For each label, the first byte is the length of the label, then the bytes for the string are written.

For your Google.com example, the labels are "google" and "com".  The `06` is the number of bytes in the first label.  This is followed by the bytes for "google".  Then the `03` is the number of bytes in the "com" label.  After the "com" bytes, the `00` byte is the NULL label to mark the end.

Comment: Aaaah very good explanation! Thanks a lot. That also means that subdomains should be divided into their own "label", with each label having a byte prefix with the length, maybe. I'll test that out. Thanks a lot!